# how to add line breaks in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I want to send a whatsapp message using this code below, but I don't know how to add line breaks in the message. I tried using `\n` but it still appears as 1 line.

**the function**

```
export function sendWhatsApp(phone='', msg='') {
  let phoneWithCountryCode = `62${ltrim(phone, '0')}`; // 628123456789
  let mobile = `+${phoneWithCountryCode}`;
  let url = `whatsapp://send?phone=${mobile}&text=${msg}`;

  Linking.openURL(url).then((data) => {
    console.log('WhatsApp Opened');
  }).catch(() => {
    alert('Please make sure WhatsApp installed on your device');
  });
}
// end export function sendWhatsApp
```

**how I call the function**

```
let msg = `Hello \n
This is first line of message \n
this is the second line`
;
sendWhatsApp('8123456789', msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"\r\n"`, it will work.

Comment: sorry, not working.. I still get one line of string instead of multiple lines